# Unique dice counter not working properly (beginner)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a dice thrower where it tracks how many unique numbers show up. For example (1 2 3 3 1 5 = 4 unique numebrs, 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 1 unique number, 1 2 3 4 5 6 = 6 unique numbers). But everytime it just returns a "0" for amount of unique numbers. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int numberGenerator()        //generates 1-6
{
int x = (rand() % 6) + 1;
return x;
}

int diceCounter()
{

int counter[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

for (int i = 0; i > 6; i++)
    {
    int k = numberGenerator();     //records if the dice number has been rolled
        if (k == 1)
           counter[0] = 1;
        if (k == 2)
           counter[1] = 1;
        if (k == 3)
           counter[2] = 1;
        if (k == 4)
           counter[3] = 1;
        if (k == 5)
           counter[4] = 1;
        if (k == 6)
           counter[5] = 1;
     }
return counter[0]+counter[1]+counter[2]+counter[3]+counter[4]+counter[5];  
}                      //returns amount of unique dice numbers


int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
cout << diceCounter() << endl;


}
```

Comment: try `counter[k-1] = 1` will still have the same problem, but code will be shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` instead of `for(int i = 0; i > 6; i++)`

Currently your loop never executes because `6` is not less than `0` and the `for()` condition fails - that's why you get all 0s.

`for(initializer; if-this-condition-is-true-then-execute-for-loop-else-dont ; increment)` <- general way to think about for loops!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop's condition is backwards, so your loop will never run:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 6; i++)
                  ^
```